# How to call async method in a method that returns Task?

Tags: c#, async-await, signalr

In the SignalR hub I've this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        // my async code here
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

I want to perform an async code. So I added `async` keyword like this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnected()
    {
        var result = await MyAsyncMethod();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

but `return base.OnConnected();` shows this error:

> Since MyHub.OnConnected() is an async method that returns `Task`, a
>   returned keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you
>   intend to return `Task<T>`?

How can I fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `async` method is converted into a state machine by the compiler. You cannot `return` that `Task` here, because the `Task` returned is generated by the compiler and represents the *continuation* of this method.

Simply `await` the `base` call:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{
    var result = await MyAsyncMethod();
    await base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If I'm not mistaken, `OnConnected()` didn't change and is still a task for caller method?

Comment: @Blendester yes.